# Issues retrieving data on Android with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm just learning how to set up Firebase data in Android. I am able to write to the db, but I am unable to read it and display it back on my app. My app is very simple (It just has one main screen for now) and I don't care how the data is displayed on the page as I am just learning - I'm trying to display it in a text view for now.

Here is my Main Activity java:

```
package com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://blistering-torch-9015.firebaseio.com");

    class User {
        private int birthYear;
        private String fullName;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(String fullName, int birthYear) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.birthYear = birthYear;
        }

        public long getBirthYear() {
            return birthYear;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }
    }

     User user1 = new User("Name 1", 1982);
     User user2 = new User("Name 2", 1972);

     Firebase usersRef = ref.child("users");

     Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
     users.put("user1", user1);
     users.put("user 2", user2);

    usersRef.setValue(users);

    Firebase postRef = ref.child("posts");

    Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post1.put("author", "user1");
    post1.put("title", "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language");
    postRef.push().setValue(post1);

    Map<String, String> post2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post2.put("author", "user2");
    post2.put("title", "The Turing Machine");
    postRef.push().setValue(post2);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
            //System.out.println(arg0.getValue());
            TextView textViewSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
            textViewSample.setText(arg0.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("the read failed");
        }

    });
}}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sampleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, it crashes. Here is the logcat error message:

```
12-27 12:15:02.678    1895-1895/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication I/art﹕ Not late     enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-27 12:15:02.946    1895-1907/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication I/art﹕ Background     sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3867(286KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 1009KB/1135KB, paused 2.595ms total 117.910ms
12-27 12:15:03.317    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
12-27 12:15:03.320    1895-1895/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6667e80, tid 1895
12-27 12:15:03.327    1895-1895/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
12-27 12:15:03.391    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa66ef3b0, tid 1926
12-27 12:15:03.405    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-27 12:15:03.422    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-27 12:15:03.439    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-27 12:15:03.439    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa66b7880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-27 12:15:07.474    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-27 12:15:07.474    1895-1926/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa66b7880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-27 12:15:13.993    1895-1895/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕    Shutting down VM 

--------- beginning of crash
12-27 12:15:13.993    1895-1895/com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication, PID: 1895 com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type 
        at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:196)
        at com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:79) 
        at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration$1.run(ValueEventRegistration.java:48)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
        at [Source: java.io.StringReader@c8f7297; line: 1, column: 1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:46)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
        at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:192)
        at com.example.ispotrachel.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:79)
        at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration$1.run(ValueEventRegistration.java:48)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)device not found
```

Comment: What happens instead of working? (E.g., error messages.)

Comment: @ispotrachel: please add that stack trace to your question, by clicking the edit link under it. That will also allow you to format them into something more readable.

Comment: All, @FrankvanPuffelen, I updated my question with the error message. Thank you!!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line that crashes, I suspect that you will find that `arg0.getValue()` returns a `Map<String, String>`. If that is the case, you can get the title of the post with something like `((Map<String,String)arg0.getValue()).get("title")`. Have a look at the example here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-types

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen. When I follow the tutorial, I'm able to do a system.out.print. The issue comes to when I try to print the data in a list or text box in the app.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

It looks like you're trying to load a JSON object into a String.

The error message `Failed to bounce to type` indicates that the Firebase client got back some data, but is unable to convert it into the type you specified.

**Details about the problem**

You're adding a `ValueEventListener` to the root of your Firebase here:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ...
```

In that value event listener you're telling Firebase to load the whole Firebase as a `String`:

```
textViewSample.setText(arg0.getValue(String.class));
```

And this would work fine if you had a very simple Firebase that only contained a single string. However, based on the rest of your code, it looks like your Firebase has a lot more than one `String` in it :)

**How to fix it**
You have a couple of options:

1. Attach your event listener further down the tree. You could get user's full name as a string:

   ```
   ref.child("users/user1/fullName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
           TextView textViewSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
           textViewSample.setText(arg0.getValue(String.class));
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or, you can get a whole user, but parse it as a `User` instead of a `String`:

   ```
   ref.child("users/user1/fullName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
           User tempUser = arg0.getValue(User.class);
           TextView textViewSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
           textViewSample.setText(tempUser.getFullName());
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem.

This is the code how I retrieve data from firebase:

```
    DatabaseReference chatRef = database.getReference("chats");
    chatRef.keepSynced(true);
    Query queryRef = chatRef.orderByChild("id");

    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
            ChatPost newPost = snapshot.getValue(ChatPost.class);
            ChatPost topic = new ChatPost(newPost.id, newPost.topic);
            addChatTopic(topic);
            System.out.println("NEW Child Topic: " + newPost.topic);

            chatAdapter.addItem(newPost);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ChatPost newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatPost.class);
            ChatPost topic = new ChatPost(newPost.id, newPost.topic);
            addChatTopic(topic);
            System.out.println("CHANGED Child Topic: " + newPost.topic);

            chatAdapter.updateItem(newPost);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ChatPost newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatPost.class);
            ChatPost topic = new ChatPost(newPost.id, newPost.topic);
            chatTopicsList.add(topic);
            System.out.println("REMOVED Child Topic: " + newPost.topic);

            chatAdapter.removeItem(newPost);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

It worked until I didn't use push() for add a new item. My data in firebase console looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDEiS.png).

The text of exception:

> 07-05 16:45:07.097 29997-29997/com.skl.bingofire E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.skl.bingofire, PID: 29997
>                                                                      com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while
>   deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zzaC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at
>   com.skl.bingofire.activities.MainActivity$7.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:228)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaer.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 07-05
>   16:45:16.924 29997-30029/com.skl.bingofire E/DynamiteModule: Failed to
>   load module descriptor class: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.skl.bingofire-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.skl.bingofire-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I used this model:

```
class ChatPost {
    public String id;
    public String topic;
    public String color;
    public ArrayList<Message> messages;
}
```

I figured out and I found that if list of data contains key for example "-KLdskjdkjkjdjksjdksjdjsdjsjk" firebase recognise the hole list as "HashMap" else as "ArrayList". I changed my model to this structure:

```
class ChatPost {
    public String id;
    public String topic;
    public String color;
    public HashMap<String, Message> messages;
}
```

And added to the rest of chats message with key like "-KLdskjdkjkjdjksjdksjdjsdjsjk". And my code now is working. But I think it is not obvious.